# Discord.Py Embed Command

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm making a bot with all kinds of commands. One of those commands is supposed to be making embeds. Such as where you say the command, the title, and the description. But the bot can only take one word as the title, and one word as the description. I need help, my code is used below. (toob is the prefix)

```
@client.command()
async def makeEmbed(ctx, title: str, description : str):
  if not title:
    await ctx.channel.send("One or more values are missing. Command should look like 'toob makeEmbed (title), (description)'")
  elif not description:
    await ctx.channel.send("One or more values are missing. Command should look like 'toob makeEmbed (title), (description)'")

  
  embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x72d345)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: maybe using `toob makeEmbed "title with multiple words" "description with multiple words"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```py
@client.command()
async def make_embed(ctx, *, content: str):
    title, description = content.split('|')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=0x72d345)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

to invoke → `toob make_embed Some Title | Some description with a loooot of words`

The downside is that you´ll need to add a `|` in the message,
here's another solution with `wait_for()`:

```py
@client.command()
async def make_embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Waiting for a title')
    title = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Waiting for a description')
    desc = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=0x72d345)
    await ctx.send(embed=embd)
```

to invoke ↓

```css
>>> toob make_embed
... Waiting for a title
>>> Some title here
... Waiting for a description
>>> Some description here
```

Or you can do what **ThRnk** suggested.

Sources:

- [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: tysm, ill try this when i get home

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    e = discord.Embed(
    title="Title Of The Embed Here!",
    description="Description Of The Embed Here!",
    color=0xFF0000 #i added hex code of red u can add any like of blue
)
await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple you can just do

`@client.command() async def make_embed(ctx, *, content: str): title, description = content.split('/') embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=color) await ctx.send(embed=embed)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).